# WinAPI LPWSTR, C++11 u16string?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, c++11

If I'm developing for Windows and some WinAPI functions require me to use LPWSTR as string data type. Is it okay to use C++11's u16string in my library? Are those two data types the same thing?

It looks more like LPWSTR is wchar_t, but nobody likes wchar_t anymore...

Comment: "*nobody likes wchar_t anymore...*" Nobody on _Windows_ has a problem with `wchar_t`, it's the people that have 4-byte `wchar_t` that don't like it. :-P

Comment: I don't like wchar_t. I have it 16 bytes. It is still less than a char. I think you should not use char16_t or wchar_t. http://www.utf8everywhere.org summarizes my view.

Comment: @ildjarn: I am on *Windows* and I *have* a problem with `wchar_t`. Narrow char + UTF-8 is the way I go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 `char16_t` type is distinct from `wchar_t`. In theory you could `reinterpret_cast` your way between `char16_t*` and Windows’ `wchar_t*` (Windows’ `wchar_t` is 16 bits). In practice, however, Visual C++ 10.0  – and I think also Visual C++ 11.0 – lacks support for Unicode literals like `u'A'` or `u"A"`.

Summing up (I’ve found that on SO one should better make all conclusions explicit):

- “Is it okay to use C++11's u16string in my library?”
  *Certainly, but not as direct plug-in replacements for `wchar_t` strings, and as of 2012 currently problematic (due to lack of support for literals) if you plan on supporting Visual C++.*
- “Are those two data types the same thing?”
  *No.*
- “nobody likes wchar_t anymore...”
  *That’s certainly not the case.*

Comment: So in the end it is best to stick on with TCHAR (or WCHAR if you dont support Win 9.x anymore) and do not use the new C++11 Unicode support at all?

Comment: @user1400869: I recommend using just `wchar_t`. Among other advantages it's less of an eyesore in the code. But it is technically possible to define a platform-dependent encoding value type, which would be mapped to `wchar_t` in Windows. Using such a type would in my opinion more in the spirit of C++ (consider other platform-dependent types such as `int`). But it is a heck of a lot of work to establish the necessary infrastructure. So, `wchar_t`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`wchar_t` and `char16_t` are distinct types, so it is not possible to use `u16string.c_str()` as a `LPWSTR` (without a `reinterpret_cast` that would cause undefined behavior).

If you are confident that on your platform `wchar_t` is encoded as UTF-16, you can *copy* the data across:

```
std::wstring my_wstring(my_u16string.begin(), my_u16string.end());
```

and then use `my_wstring.c_str()` as LPWSTR.  In a function call, you can use a temporary:

```
SomeWindowsAPI(std::wstring(my_u16string.begin(), my_u16string.end()).c_str());
```

Comment: There is no need to copy when you're in platform-specific land.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf they're distinct types though, so the implementation is not required to ensure that ensure that reading via the cast pointer has the same value as reading via the original pointer.

Comment: the compiler is part of the platform. if you use a compiler that has a bunch of problems in this regard (read: g++), then, you have to use compiler-specific solutions to the compiler's problems. that's all. the standard doesn't have platform-specific guarantees. compilers do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would you write g++-specific code when you could just write conformant code in the first place that can be used with any compiler (incl. Intel, clang, etc.)?

Comment: Since Windows and `u16string` both use UTF-16, you don't need to copy `u16string` to a separate `wstring` in order to call Windows API functions: `SomeWindowsAPI(reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(my_u16string.c_str()));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree that that would work, but it is undefined behaviour (pointer aliasing) and a sufficiently smart optimiser could break it.

Comment: I have not run into any compiler/optimizer that would break this kind of code. This is exactly the kid of situation that `reinterpret_cast` is used for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is *a* situation that `reinterpret_cast` is used for, but there are other situations that do not involve undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t` on Windows is 16-bit, and `LPWSTR` values are UTF-16 encoded, so yes, you can use `char16_t` and `u16string` values when interacting with the API, though you will have to typecast to keep the compiler happy.

Comment: And technically that typecast will cause UB, so I'd say the answer here is 'no', not 'yes'.

Comment: @ildjarn: for Windows-specific code the cast is defined by the compiler. this sort of thing is what `reinterpret_cast` is *for*.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : `reinterpret_cast` is for compiler extensions? Compiler extensions aside, the standard says this is UB, which is all I was pointing out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's the strict aliasing rule. You're not allowed to access the value of an object through an object of a different type (with some exceptions such as char). See _[basic.lval] 3.10/10_. "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:"

Comment: @bames53: it should be noted here that (1) casting between pointer to two distinct same size integers is OK wrt. to that rule, and (2) that the strict aliasing rule is defined *in terms of knowledge that the compiler does not have* (but the programmer can have), namely what the real **dynamic type** of something is. for example, what kind of value was last put in a union, by code very far away. this latter point means that g++'s impractical counter-productive behavior is simply not supported by the rule, contrary to often made claims.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't see why casting between unrelated integral types of the same size wouldn't violate strict aliasing. Which of those bullet points does that fall under? Also I'm not sure to which behavior of g++ you're referring.

Comment: @bames: re which behavior of g++ i'm referring to, i do not for a moment believe that you are really unsure about that.

Comment: @bames: re strict aliasing rule: "a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object" allows you to access a `wchar_t` as the corresponding unsigned type `unsigned short` in Windows. And vice versa. The rest is a matter of interpretation where one should first of all note that a strict formal reading (a literal interpretation) yields a *self-contradiction* via the word "the": there can be more than one corresponding integer type. Also the other rules are generally self-contradictory with a literal reading. So, some intelligence must be applied. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf wchar_t doesn't have any corresponding signed or unsigned types (corresponding types are discussed in § 3.9.1). I believe it is technically undefined behavior to access wchar_t objects through a short typed glvalue. Just because something works doesn't mean it's actually well defined. For example accessing an array of n ints as an array of 2n shorts is definitely UB under strict aliasing, but it will work just fine on many implementations.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf re behavior of g++: the only thing I can think of is if gcc complains about accessing an inactive member of a union, but that has nothing to do with the strict aliasing rule. If that's not what you're talking about then you'll have to tell me.

Comment: @barnes: you're wrong, and argumentative. the word "corresponding" applied to type is used colloquially a number of places in the standard, first referring to CV-qualification (in §3.9.3/1), then signed/unsigned-ness (which you arbitrarily chose here), placement in argument list (§5.3.4/11, §14.4/1. §30.6.9.1), and so on. "corresponding type" is *not* a defined term, and if you search for that term you find its first occurrence in §5.3.4/11 referring to argument positions. in short your selection of one particular meaning is bogus and argumentative.

Comment: @barnes: perhaps i should reiterate, that the list starts off with **dynamic type** means we're in informal-land here: it is wholly an informal term. trying to map the wording to formal definitions is therefore hopeless at the outset. then the fact that "corresponding type" isn't formally defined anywhere and is used with multiple different meanings elsewhere in the standard, makes that approach to understanding, even more hopeless. one can guess and for g++ enthusiasts hope for a particular meaning. but it doesn't make it so.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The intended correspondence is clear. In this case it means 'the same type except for signedness.' E.g the unsigned type corresponding to int is unsigned int. The underlying type of wchar_t, and the signed or unsigned types corresponding to the underlying type of wchar_t, are not the signed or unsigned types corresponding to wchar_t. It's a completely different relationship. Also, the fact that dynamic type may be unknown to the compiler does not mean it's not defined. See §1.3.7 [defns.dynamic.type].

Comment: @barnes53: contrary to your claim, and this is a direct **self contradiction** in your claims, §1.3.7 does not provide a definition of "dynamic type" the is compatible with the strict aliasing clause. §1.3.7 defines "dynamic type" as "type of the most derived object", which requires a class type, which is incompatible with your interpretation of "a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type" -- a class type has no sign. i think it's no point in discussing your other fallacious claims. i think any reader can look at the self-contradiction, and conclude from that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You should follow that definition a bit further, into §1.8 and you will find that 'most derived object' is defined such that it applies even to non-class types. Therefore so does 'dynamic type', therefore so does "the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type."

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have to wonder, class types can never have a corresponding signed or unsigned type, so if you believe that 'dynamic type' can only refer to class types what exactly do you think "signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type," means?

Comment: @barnes oh, that particular thing was fixed in C++11, via [**Defect Report 513**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#513). sorry, i didn't know. it is of course just a crutch: it's not meaningful to talk of derivation for e.g. a `float` object, plus, the term "dynamic type" is used with different incompatible meanings elsewhere (i provided a list). it's a shame that it was fixed. because it was so easy to point to when confronting g++-enthusiasts. now i'm not going to waste more time on this, sorry.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think all this talk of dynamic type is simply a red herring; even if the standard didn't define it meaningfully for non-class types it's still clear what is meant by the phrase 'the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type.' You just have to use a little common sense. It does not cover casting between unrelated types just because they're the same size.

Comment: Also, the solution for dr513 does in fact make the standard more consistent. That is a good thing. And it certainly makes sense to recognize that for an object of type float, there will be no type more derived than float, so float is the most derived type.